# Deleted wrong domain in Google reCaptcha v2

Tags: recaptcha

I have two similarly named domains that use reCaptcha.

I wanted to delete the unused domain.

I went to google/recaptcha/admin.

I deleted the wrong domain.

So now I can't access the domain.

Is there a way to restore deleted domains?

If not, how else can I get access to it?

Comment: You now have enough details that your question makes sense, but I'm not certain it's on topic on Stack Overflow. I think it is, so I've voted to reopen, but others may disagree and move you to Webmasters Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I got back in by going to the hosting platform and deleting the recaptcha folder from the plugins folder for the domain.